# Can we add travel-card tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There could be multiple questions regarding travel cards of various states in various countries. 
For example in Washington DC it's the SmarTrip card, in New York City it is the MetroCard in the USA.
In Australia, for Australian Capital Territory (ACT) it's the MyWay card and in New South Wales (NSW) it's the Opal card.

Therefore to group the questions on these travel cards related questions can we create 'travel-card' tag?

Comment: Tagging helps people find questions that may be of interest to them. Are there people who would want to follow a tag that tracked every possible transit system's card?

Comment: Well, there aren't tags for each and every transport system as well. I was initially thinking something like a set of tags, like, 'travel-card', 'NSW', 'Australia' would make the question more specific. But as per the answers provided below, 'travel-card' tag isn't a necessity.

Answer (score 9):

If I have a question about a stored value card for use on mass transit, it really means I have a question about the transit system. A question about how a Presto works is a question about how TTC works, not about what analogies I can draw from an Octopus or a CharlieCard. As such, I'd expect questions about a Rabbit Card or a TAP or a Suica to be tagged as [public-transport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-transport) plus [payment-cards](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment-cards) plus the locale (e.g. [los-angeles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/los-angeles)) until the system attracts so many questions that it merits a tag of its own (e.g. [oyster-card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oyster-card), [tfl](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tfl)).

At the least, I would advise against the term "travel card," which in my circles refers to travel-oriented credit cards like the Sapphire Reserve or the Bonvoy Brilliant cards, and which in my parents' circles refers either to "city passes" where admission to various tourist spots is sold as a bundle.

Comment: And I guessed a "travel card" was referring to passport cards/EIDs from the title.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a good idea because there are multiple different kinds of things that different people call "travel cards". And for the sense of "travel card" that you have in mind, there's a good chance that sense also goes by other terms in some places or by some people or services.

Years ago I'm sure we defined the "tickets" tag to specifically cover the kinds of travel cards which are basically various kinds of tickets/passes/etc.

Many specific kinds of tickets, passes, and cards already have their own tag. Use or create that tag and also use the generic ticket tag, that's if I've correctly assumed you're asking about the ticket sense of travelcard.

Comment: This for me.  In London, for example, "Travelcard" has a very specific meaning, and it's *not* the stored-value contactless card which is the analogue of Boston's CharlieCard.